# Does socat forward any information about source?

Tags: socat

I'm using socat in double vpn chain instead of the middle vpn server:

me(1.1.1.1)  -> socat(2.2.2.2) -> OpenVPN-Server(3.3.3.3)

I'm using it on 2.2.2.2 this way:
socat TCP-LISTEN:995,fork TCP:3.3.3.3:443

So data on 2.2.2.2 is encrypted.

Does socat send any type of information about 1.1.1.1 to 3.3.3.3 which can help deanonymize me?
(may be similiar to X-Forwarded-For or X-Originating-IP)

Answer (score 1):

You're using socat to forward a TCP stream. A TCP stream is a stream of bytes, and socat forwards it unchanged. It doesn't add any HTTP headers in the stream
 — it doesn't even know whether the stream is transporting HTTP. Above, at the TCP or IP level, there's no information about a TCP/IP connection somehow relaying another. The endpoint 3.3.3.3 only sees that it's talking to a particular port on 2.2.2.2.